# Использование javascript вместо typescript в angular

Tags: javascript, typescript

Есть ли возможность запускать js код в файле .ts? Ибо когда копирую свой js код и вставляю в файл .ts компонента, то все подсвечивается красным. Кстати, в корневой папке есть файл index.html, который прекрасно понимает js.
Вот пример кода

[image]

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})




export class AppComponent {
// title = 'RibbonlineEditor';
    var ribbon_width = 160;
    var pattern_length = 10 * 120;

    var img = new Image();
    img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
    img.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/Blank.jpg";



    var prev_left = "";
    var prev_right = "";


    function addOneData(img) {

      project_name = $("#saveprojinput").val();

        let result = idb.select("Projects", function (isSelected, responseData) {
            if (isSelected) {
                idb.insert("Projects", {
                    title: project_name,
                    img: img,
                    str1: $("#lefttext").val().toString(),
                    str2: $("#righttext").val().toString(),
                    patt_length: pattern_length,
                    date: new Date().toLocaleString(),
                    ID: responseData.length + 1
                });
                console.log("record nm: " + responseData.length);
            } else {
                console.log("Error: " + responseText);
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: покажи пример что именно, и куда ты копируешь.

Comment: а также ошибки.

Comment: js - подмножество ts (грубо говоря), любой валидный js код является также валидным ts кодом. Покажите ваш код, который не работает.

Comment: @Grundy выше добавил кусок кода и скрин. Ошибки в основном statement are not aligned и заставляют использовать const вместо var

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko по идее да, но что-то не так, выше добавил код и скрин.

Comment: собственно код рабочий, и скорее всего ты его можешь даже запустить. Данные ошибки зависят от настроек линтера

Comment: @Grundy подскажи пожалуйста, где находятся эти настройки?

Comment: тут не подскажу, но наверняка есть горячие клавиши делающие автоматическое форматирование, и автоматический фикс стилевых ошибок, типа замены на const

Comment: можешь посмотреть настройки в tsconfig.json и про eslint или tslint json

Comment: А разве запись вида `class AppComponent {
    var ribbon_width = 160;
    }` является валидным js кодом? Мне кажется, что нет.